# How to delete/unlink a file on exit

Tags: linux, node.js, windows

How do I make, in Node, so that when the process is terminated or when the execution is halted a certain file I open with `fs.openSync(filename, 'w');` is deleted/unlinked?

On windows, If I create the file and then I call `fs.unlinkSync(filename);` right after, the other program can see the file. Additionally, when the program that created it terminates, the file is also gone.

On Linux, the above is not true because after I unlink it, when the other tries to check the existence of the file it cannot find it in any shape or form I know of.
Locks are not enforced unless the drive is mounted in a specific way.
If I try to find a way to call `fs.unlinkSync(filename);` in callbacks either to `SIGINT`, `SIGTSTP`, etc... I always find a way to stop the program without the file being gone afterwards.

Please help me finding a way to create such file where being there is directly related to those files being in use.

(please ignore good practices and conventions, for now).

Comment: Certain signals are not able to be listened on, so ultimately there will be conditions where the process won't be able to unlink the file on closing, like CTRL+D

Comment: @Datsik Is there a way using the operating system?

Comment: I think this is an XY problem.  What are you using the file to do, that makes it so important that it be deleted?  For example, if you're using the existence of the file to determine whether the process is running, I believe Linux software usually uses other approaches, e.g., each running process apparently has a file-like object associated with it, so perhaps you can create a link to that object, which other processes can then check to see whether it exists.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I can't tell too much but the permissions required here are that both programs may not read nor write outside a small sandbox set of directories. I guess I'll stick with the "best-effort" way which should be good enough to do that work. In the "best-effort", unless the process is killed with SIGKILL, it will work as expected.

Comment: I'd have thought whatever was enforcing the sandbox rules should be responsible for replacing any necessary functionality that they interfere with, but I don't suppose that's under your control.  Good luck!

Comment: @HarryJohnston I get you. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap '' INT HUP TERM

read fname
read dummy

[ -f "$fname" ] && rm -f "$fname"
```

If you use *popen(3)* (or Node's equivalent) to open a pipe to that script, write a pathname on the pipe, and then **do nothing else to that pipe**, when your application exits, the invoked script will delete the file, having seen EOF on the "read dummy" line, because your app's exit will have closed the pipe to the invoked script.

I've seen similar approaches used from Java apps that really want to see some temporary directory hierarchies cleaned up on JVM exit: have the helper script do it. Just make sure that the pipe to the helper is not closed while your main application runs.

This likely fits your "ignore good practices and conventions" suggestion...

Comment: Sounds interesting but that's linux only. Did you take that into consideration?

Comment: @brunoais: according to your question, you already know how to do this in Windows!

Comment: Well, yeah, I took it into consideration. You tagged the question "Linux", after all. What @Harry said - I thought you were looking for strategies that might work on Linux, or Unix-like in general, where the OS is happy to let processes unlink open files, where coding reliable cleanup behavior in the face of app crashes, process groups, signals, controlling terminals, etc., is tricky, and a totally portable solution may not be possible.

Comment: BTW, this isn't more robust than Node running javascript. At best, this simple program is as robust as Node. It is still possible to exit the program without the file being deleted. Regardless of that, though this is a nice technique for me to use with other programs I may do, thank you.